# Implement/Substitute WHILE Loop with FOR Loop in number guessing game

Tags: java

So for my Java programming class one of the assesments is the following (a classic number guessing game):

> Write a program that plays the Hi­Lo guessing game with
>   numbers. The program should pick a random number between 11 (inclusive) and 88 (exclusive), then
>   repeatedly prompt the user to guess the number. On each guess, report to the user that he or she is
>   correct or that the guess is high or low. Continue accepting guesses until the user guesses correctly or
>   choose to quit. Use a sentinel value to determine whether the user wants to quit. Count the number of
>   guesses and report that value when the user guesses correctly. At the end of each game (by quitting or
>   a correct guess), prompt to determine whether the user wants to play again. Continue playing games
>   until the user chooses to stop. You are required to utilise at least a while loop and a for loop correctly.

So far, the game is fully working, using WHILE and IF functions. But in order to get full marks on my solution, it requires me to use at least one FOR loop, but I'm struggling to do that.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Guessing {
    public static void main (String[] args)
 {
 //Setting up the variables
 final int MAX = 88;
 final int MIN = 11;
 int answer, guess = 1;
 String another="Y";

 //Intializing scanner and random
 Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
 Random generator = new Random();
 //play again loop
 while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
 {
    //Generate a random number between 11 and 88
    answer = generator.nextInt(MAX-MIN)+11;

    System.out.print ("Guess the number I picked between "+MIN+" and "
               + MAX + "!\n");

    while(guess!=answer)
    {
       System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
       guess = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.println(answer);

       if (guess<answer && guess != 0)
           System.out.println("Your guess was too low! (0 to exit) ");
       else if (guess>answer)
           System.out.println("Your guess was too high!(0 to exit) "); 
       else if (guess==0){
           System.out.println("You excited the current round.");
           break;}
       else{ 
           System.out.println("Your guess was correct!");
           break;}
       }
    }
    //Asking player to play another game
    System.out.println("Do you want to play another game?(Y|N)");
    another = scan.next();
    if (another.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        System.out.println("Goodbye, thank you for playing");
 }
}
}
```

So far, the program works. It correctly gives higher/lower advice, the current round stops when typing in 0 as a guess and you can start another round with Y/N. But Im struggling to substitute one of the functions/loops with a FOR loop.

Comment: *"Count the number of guesses and report that value when the user guesses correctly"* There's your justification for a `for` loop. (Silly assignment though, it's really shoehorning the `for` in there.)

Comment: try `for(;;){}` It's a `while` loop in disguise

Comment: You haven't shown the number of guesses in your code.  How are you thinking of implementing that?

Comment: Does your success branch execute?  ... also, 'excited'? I think you mean exited   ;-)

Comment: @mcalex Oops, thanks for pointing that out. Somehow missed that part when reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute the central while loop with a for loop that you can also use to count the number of iterations

```
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
   System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
   guess = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.println(answer);

   if (guess<answer && guess != 0)
       System.out.println("Your guess was too low! (0 to exit) ");
   else if (guess>answer)
       System.out.println("Your guess was too high!(0 to exit) "); 
   else if (guess==0){
       System.out.println("You excited the current round.");
       break;}
   else{ 
       System.out.println("Your guess was correct!\n");
       System.out.println("It took "+i+" guesses to get the answer");
       break;}
   }
}
```

This for loop is an infinite loop because it hasn't got the second argument. However your program will exit the for loop when the correct answer is given because of the break in the final else.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now everything is working perfectly. :)

Comment: You're welcome! You should set the answer as the correct answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As the number of guesses is counted upwards, one may use the `for` loop on that.
Normally one would write `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {` but here we want to know the loop counter after the for loop and have to declare it before:

```
int numberOfGuesses = 0;
for (; guess != 0 && guess != answer; numberOfGuesses++) {
}
... numberOfGuesses
```

There is no upper limit other than finding the answer or quiting.

All three parts in `for (PARTA; PARTB; PARTC)` are optional.